# Skill under development not available on all Alexa devices

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am building a piggy bank skill for my kids (no plans to publish it yet). After completing development, the skill immediately became available in my phone's Alexa app and **one** of two Alexa devices I own (both Echo Shows). Whenever I ask the non-functioning Echo Show *ask piggy bank*, it replies with *I can't do that but for other ideas you can say, Alexa, open Amazon Kids*. What could prevent a skill from being available on one but not being available on another device?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question in case someone else runs into the same issue... It took me many hours to figure out the problem, even built a second skill and performed a full factory reset. The clue that ultimately led me down the right track was the *Amazon Kids* part of Alexa's response. On said device I had *Amazon Kids* enabled because it is in our family room, and I re-enabled it right away after the full factory reset. After disabling it, the skill under development started working as intended.